# Problema retorno de una función postgres

Tags: postgresql

Sucede que he creado un Select básico es PostgresSQL que al ejecutarlo em devuelve la información de esta manera:

[image: Select Creado]

Ahora, resulta que necesito que este select esté en una función (ya que un procedimiento almacenado no me retorna absolutamente nada), he creado el select y este funciona bien, pero la forma en lo que lo retorna no me sirve en lo absoluto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si notan, lo retorna como si fuera una sola línea de texto, necesito que me retorne como si estuviera haciendo la primera imagen, pero si o si la necesito o en un procedimiento almacenado (si es posible) o como una función (como lo tengo actualmente).

Pd: La forma en la que tengo definida el retorno de la función es
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacer que la respuesta sea igual a la primera imagen (es decir, que los valores se muestre por aparte) sin tener que plasmar el query directamente sobre el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de poner algo más de la función, pero más o menos deberías de declarar una variable de tipo record  e iterar sobre ella. Mas o menos:

```
...
DECLARE
var_r record;
...
BEGIN
FOR var_r IN (SELECT courseName, id,star_time,end_time,participans,link,duration) LOOP
courseName = var_r.courseName;
id= var_r.id;
star_time= var_r.star_time;
end_time= var_r.end_time;
participans= var_r.participans;
link= var_r.link;
duration= var_r.duration;
RETURN NEXT;
END LOOP;
....
```